# Laravel - How to delete child row when parent was deleted?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 4 tables as below:

```
class Job extend Model 
{
   public function candidates()
   { 
     return $this->hasMany(App\Models\Candidate::class);
   }
}

=========================================================
class Candidate extend Model
{
    public function skills()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(App\Models\Skill::class); 
    }

    public function job() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Job::class);
    }
}
```

So, when I delete a **job**. I want to delete all candidates who apply to this job also. But, When I delete I got this message

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`evaluation_db`.`candidate_skill`, CONSTRAINT `candidate_skills_candidate_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`candidate_id`) REFERENCES `candidates` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `candidates` where `candidates`.`job_id` = 39 and `candidates`.`job_id` is not null)
```

I think, it because of skills relation inside candidate class. Could any one help me out? I really appreciate with your help.

Thank you!

Comment: On your migration you need to add a cascade delete method, then when you delete a parent, all the children will be deleted automatically with the parent, `onDelete('cascade')`

Comment: can I use eloquent instead of schema changed?

Comment: You can do either `$job->skills->delete()` or `$job->skills()->get()->delete()` to access the `delete()` method on the model.

Comment: Thank @Espresso for your replied. But, how to access $job->skills(). because inside job model we don't have skills(). Can you check job model?

Comment: Its a belongsToMany() relationship, you can use any of these: `$job->skills()->detach();` or `$job->skills()->sync([]);` let me know if it work

Comment: Nope. Job hasMany() Candidate. Candidate belongsTo Job. The problem it pivot table on candidate_skill. So, If I deleted job data candidate that have in candidate_skill will be delete too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the behaviour in your migration.
Doc : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')
      ->constrained()
      ->onUpdate('cascade')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Hi @Bazaim, Thank you send me this. May I know other way by use eloquent instead of schema changed?

Answer (score 1):

### Delete child row when parent delete (DeleteWithRelation)

Delete all customers (children) when deleting company (parent)

```
    $companyDetails = Company::find($companyId);

    if (!$companyDetails) {
        return "Company Not Found.";
    }

    $companyDetails->customers()->delete();
    $companyDetails->delete();
```